# Ruby Block Scope with instance_eval

Tags: ruby, scope, block, proc, instance-eval

My understanding of Ruby blocks and procs was that they are all closures. Now that I've seen it in use with instance_eval, I'm a little confused.  What is the magic-sauce, the under workings when looking at the bare metal, that changes how a block's scope behaves under most common uses when compared to use with instance_eval?

Here is an example you can dump in IRB to see what I mean.  I've included both a proc.call and block yield version example.  Happily, they both behave the same way.

```
# Testing block/proc and eval
class Example
  def initialize(value)
    # value defined in the instance
    @value = value
  end

  def call_a_proc(proc)
    proc.call self
  end

  def yield_to_block
    yield self
  end
end

# Value defined in the global object
@value = 1
example = Example.new 'a'

# the block/proc that prints @value
proc1 = -> instance { puts @value }

# instance calling/yielding the block/proc that prints @value
proc2 = -> instance { instance.call_a_proc proc1 }
proc3 = -> instance { instance.yield_to_block &proc1 }

# instance_eval of the block that prints @value
proc4 = -> instance { instance.instance_eval &proc1 }

# the block/proc reference @value from the global context, the context in which it was defined (standard closure)
example.call_a_proc proc1
example.yield_to_block &proc1
example.call_a_proc proc2
example.yield_to_block &proc2
example.call_a_proc proc3
example.yield_to_block &proc3

# block/proc has it's context redefined as coming from within the instance.
example.call_a_proc proc4
example.yield_to_block &proc4
```

I understand that this is the point of the instance_eval method, I'm just not exactly sure how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define `@value` in the lexical scope (your main source file), you're defining an instance variable in the global interpreter. For example:

```
self #=> main
# "self" here refers to the main interpreter, which is of class Object
self.instance_variable_get(:@value) #=> 1
# "example" is your instance above
example.instance_variable_get(:@value) #=> "a"
# "self" has been changed to refer to "example" using instance_eval
example.instance_eval { self.instance_variable_get(:@value) } #=> "a"
# this syntax is just a shortcut for the line above
example.instance_eval { @value } #=> "a"
```

With `instance_eval`, all you're doing is replacing the main interpreter `self` with the object you've called `instance_eval` on.

Comment: The Binding class, perfect! I'll dig more into this magic when I have a spare weekend, hahah.  Thanks!

Comment: No, `instance_eval` doesn't change the `Binding` of the block. Quite the opposite, actually: the local variable bindings are pretty much the only thing it *doesn't* change. What it changes, is the value of `self`.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the error, and thanks for the comment. Just cracked the metaprogramming ruby book again and will update the answer.